# What is the verb meaning someone is stuck at home for such a long time that the person starts to exhibit psychological issues?

Tags: verbs

I saw it on Youtube one time showing people started looting and other violence in the street as a side effect of the COVID-19 lockdown.

Comment: MOD NOTE: Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box.

Answer (score 8):

Possibly [cabin](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cabin) as a verb which Lexico defines as:

> Confine within narrow bounds

This would fit nicely as the same dictionary defines [cabin fever](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cabin_fever) as a North American informal term meaning:

> Lassitude, irritability, and similar symptoms resulting from long confinement or isolation indoors during the winter.

Both terms come from the noun "cabin" which is a small dwelling often made from locally sourced timber or other material. "Cabin fever" seems to relate particularly to the psychological effects of being cooped up indoors by severe winter weather. The verb "to cabin" is not common but could well be what you are looking for.

Comment: I agree with "cabin fever", but the definition of "cabin" you quoted only refers to being confined and not to the psychological effects thereof the question is asking about. It also seems to be referring to the person confining someone as opposed to the person being confined (even if it could be the same person in this and some other contexts).

Comment: How about cooped up?

Answer (score 3):

The actual verb I think of is [**confine**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confine).

> **1 a** : to hold within a location
>        // Dikes *confined* the floodwaters.
> **1 b** : IMPRISON
>
> //  the accused was *confined* until the trial could take place

Although psychological issues don't *necessarily* result, they sometimes can, especially if somebody, such as a prisoner, is mistreated during *confinement*.

During the COVID-19 lockdown, people have been *confined* to their homes.

---

One expression that goes alone with *confinement* is [**stir-crazy**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stir-crazy):

> *slang*
> : distraught because of prolonged confinement

Comment: I think the asker is looking for a verb specifically referring to the (possible) effect of confinement, not to the act of confining.

Comment: @NotThatGuy, But this answer also offers **stir-crazy** which works perfectly in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I'll propose [cracked](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cracked).

> **2** : mentally disturbed : crazy

It's an adjective, but in this use it derives from one of the senses of the verb [crack](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crack).

> **3** : fail: such as
>
> **a**: to lose control or effectiveness under pressure — often used with up.
>
> //
> The stress was so great that she started to crack up.

I can't find a YouTube video related to looting as a side effect of the lockdown with "cracked" in the title, but it's in the right vicinity.

A possible use in such a title could be "People locked down for months have finally cracked."